# How to view the address of string, to check its (reference) type in C#?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;

Method();

unsafe void Method()
{
    string a = "hello";
    string b = a;
  //or: string b = "hello"; 

    Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)); // True.

    string aa = "hello";
    string bb = "h";
    bb += "ello";

    Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(aa, bb)); // False.

    int aaa = 100;
    int bbb = aaa;

    Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(aaa, bbb)); // False.

    string* pointer1;
    string* pointer2;

    string word1 = "Hello";
    string word2 = "Hello";

    pointer1 = &word1;
    pointer2 = &word2;

    ulong addr1  = (ulong)pointer1;
    ulong addr2 = (ulong)pointer2;

    Console.WriteLine($"Address of variable named word1: {addr1}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Address of variable named word2: {addr2}");
}
```

Why different locations?

It works correctly with object/string.ReferenceEquals. But I can't see the ADDRESSes of strings. Beginner in the world of IT. Be kind, people.

Answer (score 1):

We'll start from here:

```
string word1 = "Hello";
string word2 = "Hello";
```

It seems you expect `word1` and `word2` to refer to the same string object in memory. But that's not how it works for normal objects (strings can be a little different... we'll get there). For normal reference types, you should expect two different objects. The two objects have equivalent values, but they are still different objects.

This is important. Imagine the next line changed the string for `word1`. You would **not** want the `word2` variable to also change.

Now, strings are a little bit "special" in this area. Depending on which version of .Net you're running, the compiler may opt to [**intern**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#remarks) equivalent strings. This means it will use the same object in memory for strings with equivalent values.

This is possible because strings are **immutable**. That is, calling, say, `word1.Replace("e", "3")` does not change the value of the string in `word1` to instead be "h3llo", and therefore `word2` is also not modified by changes made from `word1`. Instead, the `Replace()` call returns a *new string*. Additionally, *all* the string methods and properties work this way, such that there is no way to change an existing string in-place.

If you want `word1` to receive that new value, you must also assign it to the variable: `word1 = word1.Replace("e", "3");`. Since this is a new assignment and only assigns to `word1`, the `word2` variable will still show "hello". So everything works as expected, and you were able to save some memory use while the two values were equal. Again: strings have special treatment here, and this is a little different from how most reference objects work by default.

---

But there's another important thing to understand about memory managemnet in .Net. The Garbage Collector can sometimes **move objects to new locations**. This means any address you see at one moment may not be the address it uses the next moment. This can especially happen during the **compaction** phase of garbage collection.

Now, it is possible to **pin** objects via [the `fixed` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/fixed), but this is not usually a good idea; it's something to avoid unless you *really* need it: say to pass the object to an outside unmanaged library. There are a number of reasons for this, but one is it prevents the garbage collector from collecting the resource at all until the `fixed` block closes.

Comment: Brother you are right. Actually I use .Net 7 and C# 11. But look, string word1 = "hello"; string word2 = "hello"; = in this case, these variables uses only 1 location, not 2, like as string word1 = "hello"; string word2 = word1; . Otherwise, when we use object/or/string.ReferenceEquals, it will showed you FALSE, but it shows you TRUE. And also, in your example at the beginning, if the next line will change the word1, word2 won't be changed, 'cause i tried and know that string is immutable. And about Garbage Collector, i don't think, that in this case it works.